# Validation rule for new record

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule

I'm trying to add a validation rule for a custom field(`Service_Date__c`) in `Case` object. If a `Service_Date__c > today()`, then error message should be displayed as :

> Service Date should be greater than today

But the rule should fire only for new records. I tried like this :

```
ISNEW(Service_Date__c > today())
```

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'isnew()'. Expected
>   0, received 1.

What am i missing? How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
ISNEW() && Service_Date__c <= today()
```

IsNew doesn't neeed any parameter. It returns true for insert and false for rest.

Comment: the following code ISNEW() && Service_Date__c >today(), not throwing any error. But when i create a new Case record, the validation rule not getting fired.

Comment: @user42000 - I modified the answer to reflect that the Service_Date__c should be **greater** than today. So it will fire if new and service date is < or = today

Comment: You need less than today or greater than today.

Comment: Service Date should not be less than today

Comment: @Eric have changed it now. Use the modified rule. It will work.

Comment: @user42000 - Exactly. Validation rules fire when evaluated to true. You only want them to fire when the rule is true. In your case, you do not want the service date be < or = today so that is what you want evaluated. You are testing for the opposite of what you want to happen essentially

Comment: Its working fine. I gave the rule condition is true that's why it's not getting triggered.